# "docker volume" vs "docker run -v"

Tags: docker, docker-volume

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
    --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
    foo
```

if I create a volume as such, how would I consume it?

```
docker run -v foo:/foo?
```

Then, what's the benefits of creating the volume first? couldnt I also do

```
docker run -v /path/to/dir:/foo?
```

if `/path/to/dir` is already NFS mounted on the host?

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the `-v` or `--volume` flag was used for standalone containers and the `--mount` flag was used for swarm services.

You can also use `--mount` with standalone containers. In general, `--mount` is more explicit and verbose.

**The biggest difference**

- the `-v` syntax combines all the options together in one field.
- the `--mount` syntax separates them.

> If you need to specify volume driver options, you must use --mount

Read [details here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-a-volume-using-a-volume-driver)

Comment: when would i need to specify volume drive options. NFS mount works fine via -v w/o me specificng driver option that it is NFS mount

Comment: There are other volume driver with authentication features. There you can enable authentication and also authorization

Comment: @ealeon, did you use `--mount` flag?